# How to compute surface integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

If i have a body under water in hydrostatic equilibrium (see the figure).

[image: figure]

How can i find the hydrostatic force that is exerted on the lower part of the body? (on the angled surface). I know i have to do the surface integral $P$$dA$. If im not wrong the pressure of the lower liquid is $P$=$P_0$ + ${\rho}_{1}$${h_1}$g+${\rho}_2$$h$g where $h$ is an arbitrary depth for lower liquid, so i have to integrate over the lower surface of the body, but im not sure how to write the area differential, and also I dont which limits of integration I should use.

${\rho}_1$, ${\rho}_2$ and ${\rho}_c$ are the densities of the upper liquid, lower liquid and body respectively

Answer (score -1):

If $z = A(x,y)$ is the surface of integration then you find a vector normal to that surface= $(-dA/dx,-dA/dy,1)$.Then evaluate the dot productor with the assosciated vector field then perform simple double integration.

Comment: @santijrv look at my answer please.